# tensorboard showing the epoch loss and accuracy for validation data but not training data

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am doing binary classification using CNN and viewing the results using tensorboard. The problem is that the tensorboard is not showing the loss and accuracy for training data.

[image: This is the screen shit of tensorboard]

As seen curves for training data are not shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to know what is happening from just that screenshot and no code.

The training and validation plots are usually separated on the page, not lines on the same graph.

If you are using Tensorflow 2.0, there is a [**known issue**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2911), regarding the syncing of TB and the `tfevent` file (where logs are stored). A couple of things to try:

1. Try adding the `TensorBoard` callback with the argument: `profile_batch=0`
2. Try restarting the tensorboard a few times... reading can fail or be very slow to load

I am referring to the [**`tensorflow.keras` API**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard):

```
tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs', update_freq='epoch',
    profile_batch=0,                      # <-- default value is 2
)
```

Comment: Yes thank you, it was slow to load it appeared after sometime. Thank you !